# python tests error when writing code for a already written test

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is my code for an already written test:

```
def scan(self, *words): # '*words' lets you give a variable number of arguments to a function
    if len(words) <= 1 and words in direction:
        r = [('direction', words)
    else:
        for i in words:
            r = []
            r.append('direction', i)            
return r
```

Here is the test:

```
from nose.tools import *
from LEXICON import lexicon

def test_directions():
    assert_equal(lexicon.scan("north"), [('direction', 'north')])
    result = lexicon.scan("north south east")
    assert_equal(result, [('direction', 'north'),
                         ('direction', 'south'),
                         ('direction', 'east')])
```

This is the error I get when I run this code:

```
ERROR: Failure: SyntaxError (invalid syntax (lexicon.py, line 19))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 418, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/home/george/Documents/git-docs/pythonlearning/ex48/tests/lexicon_tests.py", line 2, in <module>
    from LEXICON import lexicon
  File "/home/george/Documents/git-docs/pythonlearning/ex48/LEXICON/lexicon.py", line 19
    for i in words:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.004s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Question:
What is the error in the for statement?

Comment: Missing `]` in the line above. Also, the `return` is wrongly indented. Also, you are passing two arguments to append (instead of a tuple), and the `words in direction` also seems strange, `words` being a list.

Comment: don't know what exact thing you want but now `]` is the reason for the current error.

Comment: Thanks tobias i see the missing `]` . Please I want to append several tuples to the r variable if user gives more than one argument. What I have there only gives this `[('directory', 'north south')]` but what I want is `[('direction', 'north'), ('direction', 'south')]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate problem is a missing `]`, but there is more beyond that simple typo:

- `words in directions` does not seem to make much sense, as `words` is still a list, even if it has only one element; you could use `words[0]`, but this will fail in case `words` is empty
- the list initialization `r = []` is in the loop, i.e. it will always only contain the last element
- you can not pass two arguments to `append`, you meant `append(("direction", i))`
- the `return r` is on the wrong level of indentation

Also, you can turn that entire function into a single list comprehension:

```
def scan(self, *words):
    return [("direction", w) for w in words if w in directions]
```

Example:

```
>>> directions = ["north", "south", "east", "west"]
>>> lex = lexicon()
>>> lex.scan()
[]
>>> lex.scan("north")
[('direction', 'north')]
>>> lex.scan("north", "south", "west", "not a direction")
[('direction', 'north'), ('direction', 'south'), ('direction', 'west')]
```

Note, however, that `*words` assumes that the words will be passed into the function individually, e.g. as in `scan("i", "went", "north")`. If, instead, you want to call it as `scan("i went north")`, you have to `split` the sentence into words inside the function:

```
def scan(self, sentence):
    words = sentence.split()
    return [("direction", w) for w in words if w in directions]
```

Comment: Tobias if I pass `scan('i went north')` it returns empty list!

Comment: Because `"i went north"` is a single string, i.e. `*words` is `["i went north"]`. If you want `*words` as `["i", "went", "north"]` you should call as `scan("i went north".split())`, or `split() inside the method (and change the parameter `*words` to `sentence` or similar to make this clear).

Comment: you killed it Tobias, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You missed to add closing brace ']' on line 3.
Change it to

```
def scan(self, *words): # '*words' lets you give a variable number of arguments to a function
    if len(words) <= 1 and words in direction:
        r = [('direction', words)]
    else:
        for i in words:
            r = []
            r.append('direction', i)            
    return r
```

Comment: This still has multiple errors in it.